# Using window.pushState with url change with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a project that with every link clicked, the history.pushState gets activated and an address is being updated accordingly. I then have an ajax function that only loads the partial page. When the partial page is loaded, I then click on the item and the page gets redirected. However, when I click the back button, all I see is the partial ajax page and not the parent page.
Here's my code:

```
$('#brands a').click (function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    history.pushState({}, '',  href);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: '{{route("show.watches")}}',
        success: function(data) {
            $('#product-items').html(data);
        }
    })    
})
```

The `product-items` loads items while the parent page retains the old information. I then click on the item and the page gets redirected. However, when I click the back button, all I see are the items without any styling and the parent page is gone. I was told to put

```
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    location.reload();
};
```

in my partial page, that's being loaded but it doesn't get activated until I press the back button the second time. What am I missing? Can anyone help?

Comment: I mean... the way it's supposed to work is you listen to the popstate then change the content of the page to reflect the new url... not just reload the page. Just reloading the page kinda defeats the purpose?

Comment: you should probably look into the [memento pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento) you want to save your state before replacing the new data and then be able to restore it.

Comment: @KevinB  I know I shouldn't reload the page but how do I load a full page when I click the back button?

Comment: you don't, when you change the url, you note the state of the page you are changing to as part of that action. then when you go back to that state, you have data you can use to update the page to match the state that it was when that occured.

Comment: how do I accomplish that? Where do I get the previous data and how do I save it?  @KevinB